# post method is not working express js while get method working fine

Tags: node.js, express

I write this url but does not work send 500 internal server error but when I set it to get method it does work perfectly

Why this behave weird ?

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');
app.use('/api/v1/auth', apiAuthRoutes);

router.post('/test', function(req, res) {
      res.send("should work");
    });
```

Comment: Can you add more context to your question, As of not it is very difficult to point where the issue is.

Comment: post method does not work for me if I put router.get with same context does work

Comment: how do you check if the post request work? postman?

Comment: Yes from postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the sequence

```
app.use('/api/v1/auth', apiAuthRoutes);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');
```

It should work !